# uncheck checkbox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I uncheck all of `input[name='select-check']` on click of the `.toggle` button?

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if ($("input[name='select-check']:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    $(".select-all").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">remove checks.</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `if` code. You can just `.prop("checked", false)` directly. And use `select-check` for name selector.

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $("input[name='select-check']:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">remove checks.</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
 <input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
 </label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
 <input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
 </label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong class (selector), instead of `.select-all` you need to use `.select-input`. Because your check boxes has `class="select-input"` not `class="select-all"`

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if ($("input[name='select-check']:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    $(".select-input").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">remove checks.</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same `selector` you used in the `if` condition

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if ($("input[name='select-check']:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    $("input[name='select-check']").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">remove checks.</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".toggle").on('click',function() {
    $("input[name='select-check']:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">remove checks.</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label class="pick-select">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```